# How to export content of a page header band in JasperReport to Excel's header?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I need to export reports from Jasper to Excel. I am using iReport 5.6.0. The thing that I don't know how to achieve is to export content of a page header band to appear in Excel's header, and similarly, the content of a page footer band to appear in Excel's footer.

I'm aware of property e.g. `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.footer.center`, but with that I can only set static text in Excel's footer.

Answer (score 0):

There is an equivalent property for setting the header called net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.header.center (http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.header.center).  
To set a dynamic value - in the Add/modify property window, select the 'Use an expression' checkbox and then you can use whatever expression you want.

Comment: Thank you for answering quickly, but I can not find a way to set dynamic value for report scope property, where this property belongs. I can only do that for report element properties.